# Azure a connection attempt failed

Tags: azure, sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-azure

I've a sitecore azure deployment 2.0. Unfortunately, when I try to run this from company network I get the error below:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond 213.199.180.206:80

When I try below on the same machine it works:

1. http://www.google.com
2. https://www.google.com

Wondering what exactly is causing the above issue given both 443 and 80 works well via IE.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely sounds like a corporate firewall/gateway problem.  Have written a blog post with my experiences of just these types of issues.  http://reservoirdevs.wordpress.com/2013/10/18/sitecore-azure-walkthrough-and-gotchas/

My solution was to try from outside the corporate network.  It then worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like your firewall on your Azure machine is not set to allow incoming http traffic on port 80. Although there could be a lot of other reasons for this timeout.

Comment: Interesting why would azure deployment require incoming traffic for port 80? I've done only azure content delivery installation.